# How to avoid material copying error message in Edit-mode?

Tags: unity, c#

I created a component called "AphaGroup" (an analog of the existing [CanvasGroup](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/class-CanvasGroup.html) for UI) which should be able to change `alpha` of the whole game object tree. My component finds all the `MeshRenderer` components, takes their `material.color` and changes its `alpha`. It should work both in play- & edit- modes. When it's run in edit-mode there is an error in the console when the material is copied for the first time:

> *Instantiating material due to calling `renderer.material` during edit
>   mode. This will leak materials into the scene. You most likely want to
>   use `renderer.sharedMaterial` instead.*

I've read most of the similar questions on the Internet but still haven't found the answer on how to manage this situation properly. **How to avoid both: this error message and memory leaks?**

I tried [Renderer.material](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-material.html), [Renderer.materials](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-materials.html) and [Renderer.GetMaterials](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer.GetMaterials.html), but all they cause the same error.

Comment: Did you try the one thing suggested in the error message: renderer.sharedMaterial ? [I give an overview of options for avoiding the .material getter in this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/179666/39518).

Comment: @DMGregory `sharedMaterial` doesn't suit because it will change transparency for all the objects which use the same material in the scene. I will read it.

Comment: No it won't, if you use it correctly. There's a reason it's being recommended in the error message

Comment: If I create a copy via `Instantiate(material)` then I should set it to the `renderer.material`, in this case, who is responsible for destroying the previous instance of `renderer.material` which is replaced with a new one?

Comment: If you want a material to be destroyed, you are responsible for destroying it. But usually for a case like this, the previous value was an asset that you do not want to destroy. It's OK for it to simply sit unreferenced by any active game objects, but still exist in your game asset files.

Comment: Of course, I missed the fact that this is original material, thank you!

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please feel free to post your solution as an Answer below to help future users dealing with similar issues.

Comment: My solution works only in Play-mode. I'm still getting the same error in Edit-mode when I try to assign instantiated material to `meshRenderer.material`.

Comment: This may be a reasonable error, since instantiating materials (in memory) in edit mode does not make sense.

Comment: It makes sense, as long as you remember to clean up. Did you try assigning to sharedMaterial instead? And when do you remove the material afterward? Want to edit your question to show your updated code?

Comment: It worked out with your help. The code is posted, but it was checked only for my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original goal was to create a component similar to [CanvasGroup](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/class-CanvasGroup.html) in the UI system that would work for [Sprites](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Sprites.html). Then I needed it to work with [MeshText](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextMesh.html) components as well - that's where I encountered the error described in my question.

Given my original goal, *the code was tested on those components (sprites & text)* and I can't guarantee that it works correctly with any other materials. For example, transparency of some materials wouldn't be changed if their *RenderingMode* is not `Fade` or `Transparent`, or their shader is not *"Transparent/Diffuse"* (it can be changed with `material.shader = Shader.Find("Transparent/Diffuse");` or in the Inspector).

> AlphaGroup.cs

```
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

/// <summary>
/// Controls the transparency of the entire object (including all children) as `CanvasGroup` does in the UI system.
/// Executes both in play- & edit- modes.
/// </summary>
[DisallowMultipleComponent]
[ExecuteAlways]
public class AlphaGroup : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(0f, 1f)]
    [SerializeField]
    private float _alpha = 1f;

    private float _prevAlpha;
    private Renderer[] _renderers;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _renderers = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        UpdateAlpha();
    }

    private void UpdateAlpha()
    {
        if (_prevAlpha == _alpha)
            return;

        for (int i = 0; i < _renderers.Length; i++)
        {
            var renderer = _renderers[i];

            if (renderer is SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer)
            {
                var color = spriteRenderer.color;
                color.a = _alpha;
                spriteRenderer.color = color;
            }
            else if (renderer is MeshRenderer meshRenderer)
            {
                IsCopyMaterial isCopy = renderer.gameObject.GetComponent<IsCopyMaterial>();
                Material[] materials;

                if (isCopy)
                {
                    materials = meshRenderer.sharedMaterials;
                }
                else
                {
                    materials = meshRenderer.sharedMaterials.Select(m => Instantiate(m)).ToArray();

                    for (int j = 0; j < materials.Length; j++)
                    {
                        var material = materials[j];
                        material.name = meshRenderer.sharedMaterials[j].name + " (copy)";
                    }

                    meshRenderer.sharedMaterials = materials;
                    meshRenderer.gameObject.AddComponent<IsCopyMaterial>(); // Create a copy of the renderer materials only once.
                }

                foreach (Material material in materials)
                {
                    if (!material.HasProperty("_Color"))
                        continue;

                    var color = material.color;
                    color.a = _alpha;
                    material.color = color;
                }
            }
        }

        _prevAlpha = _alpha;
    }
}
```

> IsCopyMaterial.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// An indicator that the material has been copied.
/// </summary>
[DisallowMultipleComponent]
public class IsCopyMaterial : MonoBehaviour
{
}
```